# Remove pixel patches according to patch size

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi

Is there any way to remove pixels from a classified image? For example, I made an NDVI classification in Google Earth Engine Code Editor and I only want to have the classified areas with an area larger than one hectare. What could be done to remove all pixels that do not meet this condition?

Comment: Please, add the code you have or a reproducible example to let us know exactly your situation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.